# Check the number of DOM "travels" when using a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

I would like to count and test the number of hits jQuery does when i use certain functions (reading the docs not helping much).

For example:

```
var $e = $('#someId');
var result = $e.is('div');
```

Do we hit the dom twice? or do we use a "cached" object and got the answer already in our object?

My question is how can i count the number of hits made against the DOM?

Comment: Are you asking if JavaScript "caches" objects when put in a variable, or are you asking how you can prove that? (Those are two different questions.) Whatever be the answer, for readability and consistency's sake it is highly recommended to use variables.

Comment: i'm asking how can i count the number of hits made against the dom. i've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: This was interesting for me, No it not hit the DOM twice, I select item  into variable and then changed its tag name from developer inspector and found `$e` is variable and `.is()` operate on it directly. 
I also tried to `$e.remove()` and was removed of html, although I stored it on variable `$e` and I append it again on the `html`

Comment: You could try getting the non-minified jQuery script and watch it run using a debugger. After finding the code segment(s) that do the traversals, you could modify the script with counters, then run your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try monkey-patching document methods with your own methods which count how many times they were called, i.e.

```
  function watchDom() {
    var originals = {};
    var domHitsCnt = 0;
    for (var method in document) { 
      if (typeof document[method] !== 'function') {
        // skip all non-function members of document object
        continue;
      }
      (function(method) {
        originals[method] = document[method]; // save original doc. method
        document[method] = function() { // replace original doc. method with the one that count calls
          domHitsCnt++;
          return originals[method].apply(document, arguments);
        };
      })(method);
    }

    // below goes the code you want to test
    var $el = $('#d');
    $el.is('div');
    console.log(domHitsCnt);
  }

  watchDom();
```

[A fiddler example](https://jsfiddle.net/b7wfsufn/3/).

Comment: i think this is the only answer that provide a functional approach of counting the DOM hits. seems like it works. i'll try to make it more generic with selector and functions as arguments.

Comment: Not that I am put out by my answer not being accepted, but while this answer gives code to actually check the number of calls, my answer details *why* that answer is only 1.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is old answer, I read open source code [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) and found the following

```
var $e = $('#someId');
```

execute on `JQuery.fn.init` it returned JQuery object warp the selected DOM element(s)

```
// HANDLE: $("#id")
                } else {
                    elem = document.getElementById( match[2] );

                    // Check parentNode to catch when Blackberry 4.6 returns
                    // nodes that are no longer in the document #6963
                    if ( elem && elem.parentNode ) {
                        // Handle the case where IE and Opera return items
                        // by name instead of ID
                        if ( elem.id !== match[2] ) {
                            return rootjQuery.find( selector );
                        }

                        // Otherwise, we inject the element directly into the jQuery object
                        this.length = 1;
                        this[0] = elem;
                    }

                    this.context = document;
                    this.selector = selector;
                    return this;
                }
```

and `$e.is('div');` is operating on the object notice `this`

```
    is: function( selector ) {
    return !!selector && ( 
        typeof selector === "string" ?
            // If this is a positional selector, check membership in the returned set
            // so $("p:first").is("p:last") won't return true for a doc with two "p".
            POS.test( selector ) ? 
                jQuery( selector, this.context ).index( this[0] ) >= 0 :
                jQuery.filter( selector, this ).length > 0 :
            this.filter( selector ).length > 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery` function, usually aliased as `$` is a convenience method wrapping `document.getElementByX` so you can search for ids with `#` and classes with `.` etc. So to answer your question, each time you call `$('#somediv')`, `document.getElementById` is called once and you are given the element wrapped as a jQuery object. Operations on this object do not hit the DOM again unless they need to find some other element to compare to, or perform some operation with.

The jQuery function for jQuery-3.1.0.js starts on line 2897 if you want to take a look for yourself.